# How to use excel macros in a shared onenote

Tags: excel, onenote, vba

Our group is currently using OneNote to share excel files. One such file being shared would benefit from the use of VBA macros, in order to keep shared data up to date, easily analyzed, etc.

Our problem is that we get error messages (will add number when I have it) when trying to run macros. As far as I can tell, what's happening is that when the excel file is opened in OneNote, a copy is created, yet the VBA code in this copy refers to the original file, not the copy, thus rendering the macro useless.

Is this explanation of malfunction plausible? If so, does anyone know how to fix the bug from past experience? If not, I'd love to know what the issue is and how to solve it.

Please let me know if I did not include enough information. I believe the issue to be general, because I have tested on very basic code; nevertheless, I'm sure there is background information I've neglected to provide.

Looking forward to finally solving this headache!

Comment: Are you able to include the code in the question? It might be a programmatic error

Comment: Hi Harlekuin, 

I don't think it's an issue with the code. For example, the following code returned the error, "Cannot run the macro ' 'Did it work1.xlsm'!Sheet1.test'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." 

Sub test()

Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "It worked!"


End Sub

All macros are enabled, so I assume the macro is not available in this workbook. Since opening the file "Did it work" from one note creates the copied filed "Did it work1," I'm assuming the macro from the initial spreadsheet is losing its references.

Does this make sense?